# React fetch returns undefined but in console it returns array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am using react-autosuggest I try to fetch the results from the server

```
getSuggestions (value) {
  const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

  if (escapedValue === '') {
  return [];
  }

  const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');
    if (!value) {
        return Promise.resolve(myArr);
    }
  fetch(`/mypoint`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((users) => {
    if (users == undefined) {

      return []
    } else {

      return users
    }
    })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })


 }
```

This returns users from server when i console log it, no problem

```
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value),
    });
  };
```

This gets suggested values from the above function however when I write
a word to input field

> The prop `suggestions` is marked as required in `Autosuggest`, but its value is `undefined`.

I get suggestions as undefined even though it console the returned values from the server

So the return inside fetch returns undefined what should I do any suggestions!

Comment: where do you render your component ?

Comment: Inside the same component as the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `asynchronous API handling` issue.In `getSuggestions`,you are returning nothing.`return` statement inside `fetch callback` will not return to `onSuggestionsFetchRequested` for `setState`.By default `getSuggestions` returning `undefined`.

**Solutions:**

Either you do

1. **promise chaining** or
2. **pass callback** whichever you find better.

**Solution using callback:**

```
function getSuggestions(value, callback) {

      return fetch(`/mypoint`).then((response) => response.json()).then((users) => {
        if (users == undefined) {

          callback(null, []);
        } else {

          callback(null, users);
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        callback(err);
      })

    }
```

**function : onSuggestionsFetchRequested**

```
onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({value}) => {

  getSuggestions = (value, (err, data) => {
    this.setState({isLoading: false, suggestions: data});
  });

};
```

Comment: @Kaan please upvote and accept it if it's working for you